# Indexing in React when rendering element through loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning ReactJS from a last few days and I encountered a specific problem of rendering elements via loop. Please throw some light on the problem

This script works fine when we are calling the `removeItem` function from `PostList` block provided
In **PostList** function block we have

```
<Post key = {index} ..... removeItem = {() => props.removeItem(index)}/>
```

and in **Post** function block we have

```
<PostButton label = "x" handleClick = {props.removeItem}/>
```

But if I pass this `removeItem` function to the `Post` block and call the function like

In **PostList** function block we have

```
<Post key = {index} ..... removeItem = {props.removeItem}/>
```

and
in **Post** function block we have

```
<PostButton label = "x" handleClick = {() => props.removeItem(props.key)}/>
```

[Wrong Implemented Code](https://codepen.io/rajexp/pen/WEmpVm)
Then there occurs some bug the removal of item  and it is not proper the item whose remove button get clicked isn't being removed but the one who is its former get removed. I assume the cause is that the removal of element from `postList` variable affects the indexing in the second case but handled properly in first case by re-rendering the `postList` again.
Can someone please through some light on how indexing works while processing elements while rendering them through a loop in React

```js
function PostButton(props){
    var style = {
        width:24,
        height:24
    }
    return (
        <button style = {style} onClick = { () => props.handleClick()}>{props.label}</button>
    )
}
function PostText(props){
    var style = {
        border:"1px solid black",
        width: props.width
    }
    return (
        <div style = {style}>{props.text}</div>
    )
}
function Post(props){
    var style = {
        display:"flex"
    }
    return (
        <div style = {style}>
            <PostButton label = "x" handleClick = {props.removeItem}/>
            <PostText text = {props.title} width = "200"/>
            <PostButton label = "+" handleClick = {props.incrementScore}/>
            <PostText text = {props.score} width = "20"/>
            <PostButton label = "-" handleClick = {props.decrementScore}/>
        </div>
    )
}

function PostList(props){
    return (
        <ol>
        {
            props.postList.map((item,index) => 
                <Post key = {index} 
                      title = {item.title} 
                      score = {item.score}
                      incrementScore = {() => props.updateScore(index,1)}                         
                      decrementScore = {() => props.updateScore(index,-1)} 
                      removeItem = {() => props.removeItem(index)}
                />
             )
         }
        </ol>
    )  
}
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {value:"", items : []}
    } 
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value:event.target.value})
    }
    addItem(){

        var itemsCopy = this.state.items.slice()
        var truncatedString = this.state.value.substring(0,20);
        itemsCopy.push({"title":truncatedString,"score":0})
        itemsCopy.sort((a,b)=>{
          return b.score - a.score;
        })
        this.setState({items:itemsCopy,value:""})
    }
    removeItem(index){
        var itemsCopy = this.state.items.slice()
        itemsCopy.splice(index,1);
        itemsCopy.sort((a,b) => {
            return b.score - a.score
        })

        this.setState({items:itemsCopy})
    }
    updateScore(index,val){
        var itemsCopy = this.state.items.slice()
        itemsCopy[index].score += val
        itemsCopy.sort((a,b) => {
            return b.score - a.score
        })
        this.setState({items:itemsCopy})
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <input value = {this.state.value} onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                <button onClick = { () => this.addItem()}>Submit</button>
                <PostList postList = {this.state.items}
                          updateScore = {this.updateScore.bind(this)}  
                          removeItem = {this.removeItem.bind(this)}
                />

            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Key` is not a prop in `React`.  A `key` is a special attribute wich help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

If you want to use this index in `PostButton` component, you should pass it separatly:

```
<Post key = {index} ..... id={index} removeItem = {() => props.removeItem(index)}/>

<PostButton label = "x" handleClick = {() => props.removeItem(props.id)}/>
```